# JDBC DATETIME Type

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc, timestamp

I have a `DATETIME` column in a MySQL database. I use `ResultSet` metadata to retrieve the column type and it returns `TIMESTAMP` which is incorrect. How can I get the correct `java.sql.SQLType` value for this column?

I will try to be more specific. I define the structure of my database in Java code. For instance;

```
Column TITLE = new Column(JDBCType.VARCHAR).size(100).title("Created");
```

And then my small validator code creates this column (assume the table definition is there). Then, later if I modify this code as

```
Column TITLE = new Column(JDBCType.VARCHAR).size(200).title("Created");
```

My small validator alters the column size to 200. To do that, I retrieve the metadata as

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
```

And then access the column properties as

```
ResultSet resultSet = metaData.getColumns(getCatalog(), schema, table, columnName);
```

This returns me `JDBCType` enumeration. Let's assume that I run this query on a `MySQL DATETIME` column. I do know that in Java, there is no such thing and its equivalent is `java.sql.Timestamp` class. But in MySQL, DATETIME is not TIMESTAMP.

How can I differentiate between MySQL `DATETIME` and MySQL `TIMESTAMP` in Java code?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` **is** the correct type. You are thinking of the MySQL datatype, and not of the way JDBC (and the SQL standard) define types.

Comment: What makes you think it's incorrect btw?

Comment: In any case, if you want to distinguish this, you probably need to use `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnTypeName`, which should return the database-specific name of the column (though I haven't verified if MySQL Connector/J returns the correct value here)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `TIMESTAMP` is the correct type in Java but not in MySQL. I need to know the exact column type (or simply its column name) as it appears in MySQL which is `DATETIME` in my case.

Comment: @OmerHalit I don't normally use MySQL, but - from a generic JDBC perspective - you should be able to get that information from `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns`, column `TYPE_NAME` (and for its name, `COLUMN_NAME`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's it. I've been using `DATA_TYPE` column which returns the java.sql.Type value instead of `TYPE_NAME` column that returns the provider-specific column type. I'll accept this if you could post it as an answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a generic JDBC perspective, you can use the column `TYPE_NAME` from [`DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)), this should return:

> **TYPE_NAME** String => Data source dependent type name, for a UDT the type name is fully qualified

In other words, it should contain the name of the data type as used in the data source (MySQL in your case should return `DATETIME`).

Note: I haven't actually verified this, my answer is purely based on generic JDBC requirements.

Answer (score 4):

## Mapping SQL types to Java types

The values in [`java.sql.Types`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Types.html) represent [SQL standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Interoperability_and_standardization) types, not Java types. For a modern enum representing the same SQL standard types, see [`java.sql.JDBCType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/JDBCType.html), an implementation of [`java.sql.SQLType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/SQLType.html).

The value [`java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Types.html#TIMESTAMP) (and corresponding enum [`java.sql.JDBCType.TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/JDBCType.html#TIMESTAMP)) represents the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP`, a date with time-of-day but lacking the context of an offset-from-UTC or time zone.

The MySQL `DATETIME` type maps to `java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP`/`java.sql.JDBCType.TIMESTAMP`. The appropriate class in Java for this type is [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class )
```

## `LocalDateTime`

To quote the [MySQL version 8 reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

This data type `DATETIME` represents a date with a time-of-day. Crucially, no indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC is present.

So this type *cannot* represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. Be careful when assigning a column this type; be sure this suits your intentions. For example, this type should *not* be used when recording the moment of a past event.

The Java class [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) matches a MySQL `DATETIME` column.

JDBC 4.2, 4.3, and later require support for the *java.time* classes such as `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

Writing to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

⚠️ Beware of `java.sql.Timestamp`, never use. That terrible class is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

The `Timestamp` class cannot represent a MySQL `DATETIME` value properly as the class includes offset/zone info which the database column lacks.

Comment: Had this answer typed up, you beat me to the punch. One addition: As you can [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/JDBCType.html), `TIMESTAMP` _is_ the right type, or at least, the only one that's available, really. JDBC and its types were designed before java.time, unfortunately. I don't actually know if `.getObject(x, LDT.class)` works for the mysql JDBC driver. Let's hope so!

Comment: @rzwitserloot I added a note that any JDBC 4.2+ driver must support *java.time*. Thanks for your comments — motivated me to add a few more details.

Comment: I understand this. I have no problem in writing or reading. Why is `DATETIME` column type is fetched as `TIMESTAMP` in ResultSet metadata? That is incorrect and doesn't let me differentiate between those two types.

Comment: @OmerHalit See the [Comment by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73967590/jdbc-datetime-type/73967623?noredirect=1#comment130602958_73967623). The computing industry, including the early versions of Java, never invented a proper date-time handling framework until *java.time* (and its predecessor *Joda-Time*). So in the old days, `java.sql.Timestamp` was all they had to use as a hack to hold your `DATETIME` MySQL value. That was a terrible, flawed hack — I imagine it created much confusion and failed software. Fortunately, we have *java.time* now.

Comment: @BasilBourque That doesn't really answer my question. The same thing happens in Java 17. DATETIME is not there yet. There must be a reason or a workaround why `java.sql.SQLType` does not hold a value for DATETIME type. I perfectly understand how we should write or read DATETIME value. I am writing a small DB validation tool which checks the column type and alters it if needed.  But in my case, DATETIME column is retrieved as TIMESTAMP column so my tool attempts to alter it to DATETIME which is already a DATETIME.

Comment: @OmerHalit (A) You lost me on your last sentence. There is no `DATETIME` class in Java. So I do not now what you mean by "attempts to alter it to DATETIME which is already a DATETIME".  (B) I don't know how to be anymore clear: `java.sql.Timestamp` was mapped to `DATETIME` as a hack, because Java failed to include any class built to represent a date with time but without zone/offset. All I can say is: Use only *java.time* classes for your date-time work. Never use `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: @OmerHalit If you mean you are programmatically determining a mapping of column type to Java class using the [`ResultSetMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html), then you need to seriously revamp your Question. You need code examples, and a minimal `CREATE TABLE` example, to demonstrate your issue. You need to specify *exactly* JDBC driver you are using, and what version of that driver. And specify what version of MySQL you are using. And what version of Java.

Comment: Just fyi, the relevant, possible types in ```java.sql.Types```  are ```DATE,TIME,TIMESTAMP,TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE,TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE```. But as @BasilBourque says, in order to address the specifics, we *need* specifics

Comment: @OmerHalit JDBC will (very likely) never add a java.sql.Types/JDBCTypes `DATETIME`, because this is already covered by `TIMESTAMP`. Your confusion stems from the fact that the MySQL datatype `TIMESTAMP` does not correspond with the JDBC and SQL standard definitions of a `TIMESTAMP`, so MySQL added a new datatype, `DATETIME`, which does (they just gave it a different name not to break backwards compatibility)