# Correct way to do a search by date java Maria DB

Tags: java, sql, mysql, mariadb

I'm using this code to search by date:

```
public List<DocumentManagerDTO> getDocumentManager(java.sql.Date fromDateInclusive, java.sql.Date toDateInclusive) {
        String query = "select * from document_manager where dataReferencia >= ? and dataReferencia <= ?";
        
        QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
        
        ResultSetHandler<List<DocumentManagerDTO>> h = new BeanListHandler<DocumentManagerDTO>(DocumentManagerDTO.class);

        List<DocumentManagerDTO> docsToRet = null;
        try {
            docsToRet = run.query(conn, query, h, fromDateInclusive, toDateInclusive);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return docsToRet;
    }
```

the idea is to mount this query, e.g.:

```
select * from document_manager where dataReferencia >= '2023-12-04' and dataReferencia <= '2023-12-18'
```

within MySQL workbench it works properly, it returns a list of DocumentManager

But when I run through java it happens that I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Out of range value for column 'dataReferencia' : value 2023-12-08 00:00:00 Query: select * from document_manager where dataReferencia >= ? and dataReferencia <= ? Parameters: [2023-12-06, 2023-12-20]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:350)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:211)
    at infoasset.mining.connection.DBInterface.getDocumentManager(DBInterface.java:188)
    at infoasset.mining.fnet.ProcessXML.processXMLs(ProcessXML.java:100)
    at infoasset.mining.entry.EntryPointMining.main(EntryPointMining.java:24)
```

but the field, dataReferencia is a DATETIME field

See create table for documentManager:

```
CREATE TABLE `document_manager` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descriptionDocument` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataReferencia` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2739 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

what's the correcy way to do a search by date in java/mariadb?

Comment: Looks like something weird is happening.  Please edit your question to show output (as text, not image) of `show create table document_manager;` and `select version();`

Comment: I added create table for document_manager; there's no jquery in this context everything Im talking about is backend

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using and to what Java class does it map the [database] DATETIME data type? My guess is that it is **not** `java.sql.Date`. Also, have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73967590/jdbc-datetime-type)? Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Hey, you have to get `Date` from you date time param and pass it to the final query just after it the query will work.

Comment: Right, I removed a jquery tag that didn't belong

Comment: @Abra I'm using org.mariadb.jdbc 2.5.2

Answer (score 0):

```
where dataReferencia >= '2023-12-04'
  and dataReferencia <= '2023-12-18'
```

Works fine *except* that it includes an extra midnight.

In MySQL/MariaDB, I prefer this formulation:

```
WHERE dataReferencia >= '2023-12-04'
  AND dataReferencia  < '2023-12-04' + INTERVAL 4 DAY
```

You can, of course, pre-compute the two dates in your app code instead.

Further, note that `'2023-12-04'` and `'2023-12-04 00:00:00'` are identical literals.

A side note:  A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE`.  So, your `UNIQUE(id)` is redundant and can be DROPped.